# PHP not receiving the content from a contact form

Tags: php, html

I need some help. I am trying to send the content from HTML form to email, using php script. ( I am using xammp localhost as server ).
The files are Contacts.html and form-to-email.php. I did some tests with different emails, but the problem doesn't fix. Any ideas of what I am missing ?
Here is my HTML

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" size="10" class="contact-inputs" placeholder="име"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="50" size="10" class="contact-inputs" placeholder="имейл"><br>
    <textarea maxlength="1000" rows="6" cols="50" name="message" class="contact-inputs" placeholder="коментар"></textarea><br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Изпрати">
</form>
```

php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "";
    exit;
}
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}
$email_from = $visitor_email;
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You received new email from $name.\n" . "with message:\n $message".
//sending email
$to = "georgiev19621962@abv.bg";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. 
header('Location: Contacts.html');
// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am not receiving the content from the html form when submitting. I just don't get the message with the content in my email.

Comment: Have you thought about using PHPMailer? Thats what I did, its a much simpler and more efficient way to send emails using PHP.

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Do you receive any messages? If no, why do you think the problem is in not retrieving data in `$_POST`?

Comment: Have you checked and enabled xammp to allow it to send e-mails?
From my starting years I remember having to jump through a few hoops to enable my localhost environment to send out e-mail.

Comment: is there additional javascript code that handles the form?

Comment: No, no javascript handles the form, only php

Comment: Just a suggestion, whenever you use the header function to redirect, make sure you exit right after it!